# Logical translation for 'at most' using FOL

Tags: logic

Only using existential and universal quantifiers, I am trying to translate the following sentence:

"At most **b** and **c** are large cubes."

Please express the properties 'large' and 'cube' using the following atomic predicates Large(a) and Cube(a).

Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: "If something is a large cube, then it is b or c."

Comment: I don't know if it helps but its equivalent to "If $x\neq y$ are large cubes, then $\{x,y\}=\{b,c\}$" so you would not have the nasty "at most"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**: For all $x$, *if* large($x$) and cube($x$) *then* $x=b$ or $x=c$.

Comment: At most, means at least one correct?

Comment: As far as I read it, at most means that if there are any there cannot be more than two.